# PHP setting session variables on button click

Tags: php, session

When a user click either 4/6 'Snacks Per Shipment', and weekly/fortnightly/monthly 'Shipment Frequency', a function displays the details on the right hand side above the button.

I'm a noob developer looking to store whatever information a user chooses, as a session variable once the button 'Choose your snacks' is clicked. In this example, I would be looking to store 4 and fortnightly.

[image]

Here is my PHP code when starting the session

```
<?php
session_start();

include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(isset($_POST['choose']))
{

$unit = document.getElementById('unit').innerHTML;
$frequency = document.getElementById('frequency').innerHTML;


// Set session variables
$_SESSION["unit"] = $unit;
$_SESSION["frequency"] = $frequency;

}

?>
```

Here is the code related to the button

```
<div class="pricing-button" method="POST">
<a href="session.php" class="btn btn-yellow btn-rounded btn-lg"
name="choose" type="submit">Choose Your Snacks</a>
</div>
```

Here is my code related to scraping what the user chooses

```
<script>
function change(unit){
document.getElementById('unit').innerHTML = unit;
}

function frequency(frequency){
document.getElementById('frequency').innerHTML = frequency;
}
</script>
```

And here's where i'm testing if the session variables are working or not

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

 <?php
// Echo session variables that were set on previous page
echo "Customer wants " . $_SESSION["unit"] . "<br>";
echo "This many times " . $_SESSION["frequency"] . "<br>";
?>
```

Comment: I may be totally off on this but isn't this javascript being mixed with php incorrectly?

$unit = document.getElementById('unit').innerHTML;

Comment: div tag has method="post"? method is attribute for form. You need to spend time on learning these languages first. You have just mixed everything!!

Comment: You seem to be very confused here. `if(isset($_POST['choose']))` is PHP, but then you have `$unit` (PHP) `= document.getElementById('unit').innerHTML;` (JavaScript). You can't pick and choose the languages like that.

Comment: Div method? A type??

Comment: As others have said, you are mixing PHP and JavaScript. You can either use JavaScript to store these info as variables and submit with AJAX, or use JS to set these info as hidden html form fields' value attributes (<input type='hidden' name='frequency' value='my_value'>) and then submit the form containing the hidden input fields by having a submit button or through JS's  form.submit function.

Comment: `type="submit"` doesn't do anything for `<a>`. That attribute is only meaningful for `<input>` or `<button>` and it has to be inside `<form>`.

Comment: I suspect what you're really trying to use is AJAX. That will require some more studying. You're really so confused about all this stuff that we can't really help you in this format. You need to take a class on web development, or at least read some good tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

On first code, you have mix of PHP/JS...

Try put unit and frequency on same form, after submit.

And remember... TurnOn **display_errors** directive on *php.ini*

Answer (score 0):

Session variables need to be assigned before the page loads. You cannot manipulate them with JavaScript. You should have the results once fully finalized submit to another page and then get the results using PHP on a new page load, or if you want to get into more complicated things submit them using ajax or something.

Your PHP should look more like this as well since you blended it with JavaScript originally.

```
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(isset($_POST['choose']))
{

$unit = $_POST['unit'];
$frequency = $_POST['frequency'];


// Set session variables
$_SESSION["unit"] = $unit;
$_SESSION["frequency"] = $frequency;

}

?>
```